# How to extract the specific part of string in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string `ST0023_Lamb_Weston_2017_US` in a table from particular column. While selecting the name I need to get only `Lamb_Weston_2017_US`. I can use

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ST0023_Lamb_Weston_2017_US', 8, 20)
```

But there will be different names in the column. For example ,

```
ST0023_Lamb_Weston_2017_US
ST0053_PL_Sandbox_Dorgan_US
ST0071_EDA_Austria
ST0071_EDA_Austria
ST10338_Nestle_Soluble_Instant_Cacao_ES
```

So the above mentioned are the different names available. I need to remove the "ST" part and the number part till first hyphen and return name alone. Please help me with this.

Comment: You can find the first underscore using the `CHARINDEX('_', 'ST10338_Nestle_Soluble_Instant_Cacao_ES')` function, then plug that into SUBSTRING(). I hate charindex() because it’s always the last function name I try after “indexof”, “strpos”, “charindex” and whatever else comes to mind…

Answer (score 0):

Inside substring function use charindex to pick the starting position of underscore. Plus one is added with charindex to exclude the underscore position and ending position will be considered till the length of the data.

```
create table data
(
value varchar(100)
)

insert into  data
select 'ST0023_Lamb_Weston_2017_US' union 
select 'ST0053_PL_Sandbox_Dorgan_US' union
select  'ST0071_EDA_Austria'  union
select  'ST0071_EDA_Austria' union
select 'ST10338_Nestle_Soluble_Instant_Cacao_ES' 
go
select value, SUBSTRING(value, CHARINDEX('_',value)+1 , LEN(value)) 'Newvalue' from data
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will check and let you know.